I want a user to get logged out if the username route param changes
This is the code and I want that the user gets logged out as soon as he tries to enters another path parameter value in the URL.
Suppose user's name is "virat" so the URL will be "http://localhost:3001/new/virat", and if they change "virat" to "rohit", I want them to get logged out.
How can I add this functionality using React?
I tried this code, but it is not working:
const { username } = useParams();

const logoutR = async () => {
  await fetch("http://localhost:3000/logout", {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "include",
  });
  navigate("/login");
};

useEffect(() => {
  let url = window.location.href;
  if (!url.includes(username)) {
    logoutR()
  }
}, [username])


The current implementation only ever checks the current username parameter value against the current URL, so it looks like it will always be a match and not run the logout handler.
You should probably track the previous username route parameter value so that when it changes you can run the side-effect to log the current user out.
Basic usePrevious hook if you don't want to add an additional dependency:
const usePrevious = (value) => {
  const previousRef = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    previousRef.current = value;
  });

  return previousRef.current;
};

const { username } = useParams();

const logoutR = async () => {
  try {
    await fetch("http://localhost:3000/logout", {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
    });
    navigate("/login");
  } catch(error) {
    // catch and handle/ignore
  }
};

// Cache the current username, access the previous username
const previousUsername = usePrevious(username);

useEffect(() => {
  if (previousUsername && previousUsername !== username) {
    logoutR();
  }
}, [previousUsername, username]);


thanks for the response brother, but this code is not fulfilling the requirement. even after changing the username i am logged in

@Thor Perhaps there is more going in your app than what is shared here. Think you could create a running Codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?
